# Cross Checking i18next property files in Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, i18next

I'm using **i18next** (and **react-i18next**) in a React application, with `translation.json` files. I use **Jest** for my testing, though... this may or may not be a Jest-based solution.

I might be getting into AI-level questions, but has anyone come up with a method to cross check the properties defined in the translation files against properties that are used in the code?

For example, given the following example:

```tsx
<div>{t('some.property')}</div>
```

A test would verify that `some.property` is defined in the translation file(s).

And, maybe more difficult:

```json
{
  "some": {
    "property": "hi there!"
  }
}
```

A test would verify that `some.property` is used somewhere in the code base.

Making things more difficult, `some.property` might be defined in the `en` translation file but not the `en-CA` file (or `fr` but not `fr-CA`), which is perfectly acceptable. But... if `some.other.property` is defined in, say, `en-CA` and not used anywhere in the code, I'd like to flag that.